# Pygame: breaking text lines to fit screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So, I'm developing a client-server application, in which the client request some information for the server, and upon receiving it, the client displays the information on a Pygame screen. The problem is that the information I get from the server comes in the form of a list (because I used the pickle library to send it), and I'm having trouble breaking this list into separate lines to fit the screen.

For instance, this is a code from the server side to send information about the server's cpu usage, memory, and such:

```
def mostra_uso_cpu_e_ram(socket_cliente):
    info1 =('Usuario solicitou Informações de uso de processamento e Memória')
    resposta = []
    cpu = ('Porcentagem: ',psutil.cpu_percent())
    resposta.append(cpu)
    processador = ('Nome e modelo do processador: ',cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()['brand'])
    resposta.append(processador)
    arquitetura = ('Arquitetura: ',cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()['arch'])
    resposta.append(arquitetura)
    palavra = ('Palavra do processador:', cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()['bits'])
    resposta.append(palavra)
    ftotal = ('Frequência total do processador:', cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()['hz_actual'])
    resposta.append(ftotal)
    fuso = ('Frequência de uso:', psutil.cpu_freq()[0])
    resposta.append(fuso)
    disk = ('Porcentagem de uso do disco:', psutil.disk_usage('/')[3])
    resposta.append(disk)
    mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
    mem_percent = mem.used/mem.total
    memoria = ('Porcentagem de memória usada:', mem_percent)
    resposta.append(memoria)
    bytes_resp = pickle.dumps(resposta)
    socket_cliente.send(bytes_resp)
    print(info1)
```

And this is the client side:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 9999))

bytes_resp = s.recv(1024)
lista = pickle.loads(bytes_resp)

# Pygame screen and surface settings 
largura_tela = 800
altura_tela = 600
tela = pygame.display.set_mode((largura_tela, altura_tela))
background = pygame.Surface(tela.get_size())
tela.blit(background, (0,0))

#function used to break lines but shows nothing
#indentation seems a little lot to the right because it's inside another block of text

       def drawText(surface, text, rect, color, font, aa=False, bkg=None):
            rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
            text = str(lista)
            y = rect.top
            lineSpacing = -2

            fontHeight = font.size("Tg")[1]

            while text:
                i = 1

                if y + fontHeight > rect.bottom:
                    break

                # determine maximum width of line
                while font.size(text[:i])[0] < rect.width and i < len(text):
                    i += 1

                # if we've wrapped the text, then adjust the wrap to the last word      
                if i < len(text): 
                    i = text.rfind(" ", 0, i) + 1

                # render the line and blit it to the surface
                if bkg:
                    image = font.render(text[:i], 1, color, bkg)
                    image.set_colorkey(bkg)
                else:
                    image = font.render(text[:i], aa, color)

                surface.blit(image, (rect.left, y))
                y += fontHeight + lineSpacing

                text = text[i:]

            return text
        
        drawText(background, str(lista), (30,400,1300,350), verde, font, aa=True, bkg=None)
```

The list I'm trying to render is this one:

```
[('Porcentagem: ', 15.2), ('Nome e modelo do processador: ', 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4288U CPU @ 2.60GHz'), ('Arquitetura: ', 'X86_64'), ('Palavra do processador:', 64), ('Frequência total do processador:', '2.6000 GHz'), ('Frequência de uso:', 2600), ('Porcentagem de uso do disco:', 11.1), ('Porcentagem de memória usada:', 0.48642539978027344)]
```

My question is: how can I break these lists into lines, or at the very least make them fit the pygame surface borders? Got this function from the pygame site but I'm not sure where am I going wrong here?

Comment: I suggest you replace the server side code with a sample of the list you want to process by the `drawText()` function. Also explain clearly how the function isn't working the way you desire. A link to source of the function on the pygame site would also be useful.

Comment: Thank you! I added the list that I want rendered to the bottom of the post. Also, I got the function from this site: https://www.pygame.org/wiki/TextWrap . It's not working since it doesn't show any kind of error, nor the result, I don't know what I'm getting wrong

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to convert the list into a list of lines of text:

```
lst = [('Porcentagem: ', 15.2), ('Nome e modelo do processador: ', 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4288U CPU @ 2.60GHz'), ('Arquitetura: ', 'X86_64'), ('Palavra do processador:', 64), ('Frequência total do processador:', '2.6000 GHz'), ('Frequência de uso:', 2600), ('Porcentagem de uso do disco:', 11.1), ('Porcentagem de memória usada:', 0.48642539978027344)]


lines = [''.join(map(str, items)) for items in lst]
print(lines)
```

Output:

```
['Porcentagem: 15.2', 'Nome e modelo do processador: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4288U CPU @ 2.60GHz', 'Arquitetura: X86_64', 'Palavra do processador:64', 'Frequência total do processador:2.6000 GHz', 'Frequência de uso:2600', 'Porcentagem de uso do disco:11.1', 'Porcentagem de memória usada:0.48642539978027344']
```

I can't easily test it since you haven't provided a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). One potential problem might be that the `drawText()` function looks like it's assuming the characters in the font are all the same width, which isn't true for all fonts.